# What's the point of a Matlab class method being both abstract and static?

Tags: matlab, oop, static, abstract

Matlab allows for class methods to be both `abstract` and `static`, which is different than many OO languages.  After trying a few cases, however, it's unclear to me how this can be used in actual code.  Consider this sample abstract class:

```
classdef (Abstract) TestParent
    methods (Access = public, Abstract = true, Static = true)
        f()
    end

    methods (Access = public, Static = true)
        function g()
            disp('Test g');
            TestParent.f();  % This line will cause problems
        end
    end
end
```

And consider this concrete child class:

```
classdef TestChild < TestParent
    methods (Access = public, Static = true)
        function f()
            disp('f child');
        end
    end
end
```

As noted in the comment on the class `TestParent`, the call to the abstract static `f()` will fail at runtime.  Specifically, from the command line, using the child class, I get:

```
>> TestChild.f()
f child
>> TestChild.g()
Test g
Error using TestParent.f
Method 'f' is not defined for class 'TestParent' or is removed from MATLAB's search path.

Error in TestParent.g (line 13)
    TestParent.f();
```

On the command line using the parent class, I get:

```
>> TestParent.g()
Test g
Error using TestParent.f
Method 'f' is not defined for class 'TestParent' or is removed from MATLAB's search path.

Error in TestParent.g (line 13)
    TestParent.f();
```

So, in summary:

- I can call `f` on the child class with no problem.  This makes sense since it has a concrete implementation in the child class.  So far so good.
- If I try to call `g` using the parent class name as a qualifier, the code crashes when it needs to call the abstract static method `f`.  This makes sense since the parent has no implementation of `f` and the call path did not go through any concrete child.
- If I try to call `g` from the child class, it recognizes that the child class has no local method with that name and goes to the parent class, where it finds and attempts to run the parent's implementation of `g`.  In this case, I was expecting it to run successfully since the call path does logically imply a concrete implementation of `f` that should be run.  Nonetheless it crashes.

The last one is the real surprise to me.  I expected that if static and abstract meant anything, it would mean that this is supported.  Given that this is apparently not supported, I'm unable to see why this combination of keywords makes sense.  Can anyone give a use case for this?

Comment: Static methods can also be called on instances. So if you have an instance then redirection will work correctly for static methods.

Comment: [How to get the name of the calling class in a static method?](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/157528-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-calling-class-in-a-static-method) seems relevant here